# im not able to submit form using update button in Selenium Java? please find below HTML

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried classname, xpath with type and name. still no use.

```
<div class="login-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your code and exception log

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

```
a) .//button[@type='submit'] or 
b) .//*[@type='submit'][@class='hvr-shutter-out-horizontal']
```

Also please mention what you have used as your xpath which was not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(uname1);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Username entered sucessfully");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(password1);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("hvr-shutter-out-horizontal")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Password entered sucessfully");
    System.out.println("logged in successfully");
    Thread.sleep(6000);

    //Edit Profile page 
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("PROFILE")).click();
    System.out.println("Profile Update page loaded successfully");
    Thread.sleep(6000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("MiddleName")).sendKeys("KS");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Middle name entered");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@type='submit'][@class='hvr-shutter-out-horizontal']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I tried above codes.still its showing unable to locate element. maybe login button also have same properties?

Answer (score 0):

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='login-btn']")).click();
```

This one worked. thanks guys.